# read integer values from a CSV file, how to get only the last two values of the record?

Tags: c

The sample record will be like this,

```
14/11/2014,Sh2345,423,10
12/12/2014,AV2345,242,20
```

From the above record I need only

```
423,10
242,20
```

The below code will give me all the row and Column count.

```
rowIndex = 0;
columnIndex = 0;
while(fgets(part,1024,fp) != NULL){
    token = NULL;

    while((token = strtok((token == NULL)?part:NULL,",")) != NULL){
        if(rowIndex == 0){ 
            columnIndex++;
        }
        for(idx = 0;idx<strlen(token);idx++){
            if(token[idx] == '\n'){ 
                rowIndex++;
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: minor: Assuming `part` was delcared as `char part[1024]` it's better to then `fgets(part, sizeof part, fp)` also, don't call `strlen` like that, store it's return value and use it.

Comment: One more thing, unless the line length is more than `sizeof part` length, the `'\n'` character will be stored at the end of `part` and hence you don't need the for loop.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the second commend.Could you please explain?

Comment: Is `columnIndex` supposed to refer to the original data (2..3) or the required data (0..1)? And note that `columnIndex` has not been reset for each line.

Comment: First I am trying to get the column and row count from the original data and then try to store the values in a matrix format.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `strtok` which I believe is the right way to do this kind of things, since `fscanf` will be very problematic in case of invalid input, then I think this is the way:

```
rowIndex = 0;
while (fgets(part, sizeof part, fp) != NULL)
{
    char *token;
    size_t partLength;
    char *saveptr; // for strtok_r to store it's current state

    partLength = strlen(part);
    /* check if this is a complete line */
    if (part[partLength - 1] == '\n')
        rowIndex++;

    columnIndex = 0;
    token       = strtok_r(part, ",", &saveptr);
    while ((token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &saveptr)) != NULL)
    {
        char *endptr;

        /* if columnIndex >= 1 then we are in the right columns */
        if (columnIndex >= 1)
            values[columnIndex - 1] = strtol(token, &endptr, 10);
        /* in case the conversion rejected some characters */
        if ((*endptr != '\0') && (*endptr != '\n'))
            values[columnIndex - 1] = -1; /* some invalid value (if it's possible) */
        columnIndex++;
    }
    /* if we have columnIndex == 3, then we've read the two values */
    if (columnIndex == 3)
        printf("(%d, %d)\n", values[0], values[1]);
    /* the last column will not be counted in the while loop */
    columnIndex++;
}
```

In case of very long lines, for which `sizeof part` is small enough to leave some `,` in between, you are going to need some different approach, but as long as the lines fit `part` you are ok.

To read the values into an array, maybe this could work:

```
int **fileToMatrix(const char *const filename, int *readRowCount, int *readColumnCount, int skipColumns)
{
    char  part[256];
    FILE *file;
    int   rowIndex;
    int   columnIndex;
    int   index;
    int **values;

    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL;
    values   = NULL; /* calling realloc, it behaves like malloc if ptr argument is NULL */
    rowIndex = 0;
    while (fgets(part, sizeof part, file) != NULL)
    {
        char *token;
        int **pointer;
        char *saveptr; // for strtok_r to store it's current state

        /* check if this is a complete line */

        pointer = realloc(values, (1 + rowIndex) * sizeof(int *));
        if (pointer == NULL)
            goto abort;

        values           = pointer;
        values[rowIndex] = NULL;
        columnIndex      = 0;
        token            = strtok_r(part, ",", &saveptr);

        while ((token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &saveptr)) != NULL)
        {
            columnIndex += 1;
            /* if columnIndex > skipColumns - 1 then we are in the right columns */
            if (columnIndex > (skipColumns - 1))
            {
                int   value;
                char *endptr;
                int  *currentRow;
                int   columnCount;

                endptr = NULL;
                value  = strtol(token, &endptr, 10);
                /* in case the conversion rejected some characters */
                if ((endptr != NULL) && (*endptr != '\0') && (*endptr != '\n'))
                    value = -1;
                /*           ^ some invalid value (if it's possible) */
                columnCount = columnIndex - skipColumns + 1;
                currentRow  = realloc(values[rowIndex],  columnCount * sizeof(int));
                if (currentRow == NULL)
                    goto abort;
                currentRow[columnIndex - skipColumns] = value;
                values[rowIndex]                      = currentRow;
            }
        }
        /* the last column will not be counted in the while loop */
        columnIndex++;
        rowIndex++;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%d rows and %d columns parsed\n", rowIndex, columnIndex - skipColumns);
    fclose(file);

    *readRowCount    = rowIndex;
    *readColumnCount = columnIndex - skipColumns;

    return values;

abort:
    *readRowCount    = -1;
    *readColumnCount = -1;

    for (index = rowIndex - 1 ; index >= 0 ; index--)
        free(values[index]);
    free(values);

    fclose(file);
    return NULL;
}

void freeMatrix(int **matrix, int rows, int columns)
{
    int row;
    for (row = 0 ; row < rows ; row++)
        free(matrix[row]);
    free(matrix);
}

void printMatrix(int **matrix, int rows, int columns)
{
    int row;
    int column;
    for (row = 0 ; row < rows ; row++)
    {
        int *currentRow;

        currentRow = matrix[row];
        for (column = 0 ; column < columns ; column++)
            printf("%8d", currentRow[column]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int **matrix;
    int   rows;
    int   columns;

    matrix = fileToMatrix("data.dat", &rows, &columns, 2);
    if (matrix != NULL)
    {
        printMatrix(matrix, rows, columns);
        freeMatrix(matrix, rows, columns);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You should also note, that sometimes fields in a CSV file contain `"` or `'` quotes, you might want to remove them from the tokens returned by `strtok_r` to avoid the failure of `strtol`.

Comment: When you say `fscanf()` can be problematic I agree if the OP is not sure about what is in the file but if the file looks to what is been posted then is there any prob with `fscanf()` i don't think so

Comment: There is no problem, but I never use any of `*scanf` functions because they are unrealiable, if there is a minimum variation in the inputs then you don't know what happened, and it may even leave some of the fields uninitialized leading to potential undefined behavior, which makes the program very dificult to debug. If one instead parses the input with `strtok` for example, you have control over possible invalid input, handling any possible errors.

Comment: The values which I need all are integer.After storing the values into matrix I need to get the sum.For eg:

Comment: Then doesn't that negate the whole idea of `*scanf()` functions? Since when we know what needs to be read before hand then these utilities are helpful . Even in this scenario if we get rid of them then where actually are they useful?

Comment: I  am getting the values from the CSV file as follows,

423 10
435 25
423 15
435 05

After this I need to get the Total of second column based on 1st column

423 25
435 30

Comment: @nimmypk the `int values[2]` array stores these values. If you need to do something with them, may be you need dynamic memory allocation or a predefined array of arrays to store all the read values, it depends on what are you trying to do.

Comment: @Gopi I simply don't use those functions ever, when a used them in the past, alwasy lead to bugs, often very hard to debug.

Comment: matc = malloc(rowMaxIndex*columnMaxIndex*sizeof(int));
    mat = malloc(rowMaxIndex*sizeof(int*));

    for(idx = 0;idx<rowIndex;idx++){
        mat[idx] = matc+idx*columnIndex;
    }

    rewind(fp);

   i = j = 0;
    while(fgets(part,1024,fp) != NULL){
        token = NULL;
        while((token = strtok((token == NULL)?part:NULL,",")) != NULL){
            mat[i][j] = atoi(token);
            j = (j+1)%columnIndex;
        }
        i++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

Comment: That code is wrong, what are you trying to do? `sizeof(int *) <> sizeof(int)` they could be equal, but you can't trust.

Comment: How are the matrix values related to the file values?

Comment: Plus 1, but note that the use of `strtok()` rather than `strtok_r()` (POSIX) or `strtok_s()` (Windows) is problematic in general-purpose code.  If you use `strtok()`, you can neither call a library function that uses `strtok()` nor can any function which is itself using `strtok()` call your code.  Using `strtok()` is therefore poisonous.  Also, CSV format in general is more complex.  Here, there are no quoted fields containing commas, but in general CSV data, you have to worry about such fields.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are right, indeed CSV files generated by various applications might include quoted fields. Regarding `strtok` I don't use it now in my code, it's easy to use `strtok_r` anyway. I will fix the answer.

Comment: @Gopi  `fscanf(fp,"%*s,...` will not scan `14/11/2014,Sh2345,423,10` as desired.  `"%s"` does not stop at `','`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int v1, v2;
while(fgets(part,1024,fp) != NULL){
    sscanf(part, "%*[^,],%*[^,],%d,%d", &v1, &v2);//skip 2 field
    //do stuff .. printf("%d,%d\n", v1, v2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Let's try with the above.

Comment: Surprised code is not check the return value of `sscanf()` for this otherwise good answer..

Comment: So I updated my Code with the above changes.From reading the values from the CSV file I need to find the Total and Mean of the second column based on first in the eg given first.For that I am using the  logic to put it into the matrix and everytime getting the value updating or adding into the matrix.But I am not sure My code is coprrect or not Please some one help me to review my code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
int CheckMatrix(int Matrix, int Checkrow, int Checkvalue) /* to check whether the area code existing in the matrix*/
 {
    int i,j;

   for(i=0;i<=Checkrow;i++)
       {
          if( Matrix[i][0]== Checkvalue)
             { 
                return i;
             }
          else
             {
               return -1;
              }
        }
 }

int **fileToMatrix(const char *const filename, int *readRowCount)
{
    char  part[256];
    FILE *file;
    int   rowIndex;
    int   index;
    int **values;
    size_t partLength;
    int v1,v2;
    int CheckValue;


    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL;
    values   = NULL; /* calling realloc, it behaves like malloc if ptr argument is NULL */
    rowIndex = 0;
    while (fgets(part, sizeof part, file) != NULL)
    {
        int **pointer;

        /* check if this is a complete line */

        pointer = realloc(values, (1 + rowIndex) * sizeof(int *));
        if (pointer == NULL)
            goto abort;
         partLength = strlen(part);
        /* check if this is a complete line */
        if (part[partLength - 1] == '\n')
        rowIndex++;
        sscanf(part, "%*[^,],%*[^,],%d,%d", &v1, &v2);//skip 2 field to get the Area code and Distance 

        CheckValue = CheckMatrix(Values,rowIndex,V1); //Call the function to check  whether the area code existing or not in the array

         If (CheckValue!=-1) // If existing the current distace will add to the existing and increase the count of areacode.
           { 
             Values[CheckValue][1]=Values[CheckValue][1]+V2;
             Values[CheckValue][2]=Values[CheckValue][2];

            }
        else // If not existing will add to the matrix as new entry.
            {
              Values[CheckValue][0]=V1;
              Values[CheckValue][1]=V2; 
              Values[CheckValue][2]=1;
            }   


    }

    return values;

abort:
    *readRowCount    = -1;
    *readColumnCount = -1;

    for (index = rowIndex - 1 ; index >= 0 ; index--)
        free(values[index]);
    free(values);

    fclose(file);
    return NULL;
}

void freeMatrix(int **matrix, int rows)
{
    int row;
    for (row = 0 ; row < rows ; row++)
        free(matrix[row]);
    free(matrix);
}

void printMatrix(int **matrix, int rows)
{
    int row;
    for (row = 0 ; row < rows ; row++)
    {

         for (column = 0 ; column < 4 ; column++)
            {   
               if (column==3)
               {
                  double Mean = double(matrix[row][1])/double(matrix[row][2]); /* To get the mean */
                  printf("%f",matrix[row][column];
               }  

                printf("%d |", matrix[row][column]);

            }

            printf("\n");
    }
}




# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int **matrix;
    int   rows;

    matrix = fileToMatrix("data.dat", &rows);
    if (matrix != NULL)
    {
        printf("|AreaCode|Total Distace|Area Count|Mean");
        printf("------------------------------------------");
        printMatrix(matrix, rows);
        freeMatrix(matrix, rows);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some there is a mistake.

Comment: 1) at `CheckMatrix` : `int Matrix` --> `int **Matrix`, `i<=Checkrow` --> `i<Checkrow`, `return -1;` move to after for-loop.

Comment: 2) at `fileToMatrix` : need allocate for column. E.g `values[rowIndex] = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));`, `V1, V2` --> `v1, v2`, `If` --> `if`, `Values[CheckValue][2]=Values[CheckValue][2];` --> `Values[CheckValue][2]=Values[CheckValue][2]+1;`,  need `fclose(file)` and update `*readRowCount` when normal end.

Comment: 3) at `printMatrix` : `double Mean = double(matrix[row][1])/double(matrix[row][2]);` --> `double Mean = (double)matrix[row][1]/matrix[row][2];` in C. `printf("%f",matrix[row][column];` --> `printf("%f", Mean);`, `printf("%d |", matrix[row][column]);` into else block or if-block move to after for-loop.

Comment: 4) Number of rows matrix and the number of lines on the file are different.